# How can we proof that number ternary strings that do not contain two consecutive 0s or 1s is $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How can we proof that number ternary strings that do not contain two consecutive 0s or 1s is

$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$

What I tried so far:

Let $a_n$ be the number ternary strings that do not contain two consecutive 0s or 1s. If the first digit start with 2 there will be $a_{n-1}$ such strings. Or if the first digit start with 0 there will be $ (2/3) a_{n-1}$ such strings. Same goes for the case starting with 1. That means $(4/3)a_{n-1}$ and in total $(4/3)a_{n-1} + a_{n-1} = (7/3) a_{n-1}$

And if the first digit is 0 and second 1 or 2 there'll be $a_{n-2}$
Similarly starting with 1 and second digits are 0 or 2 there'll be $a_{n-2}$
and  in total $ 2a_n{-2}$

So as you can see I get $a_n =(7/3)a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}$

I have no clue what I am missing here

Comment: Have you tried looking at the last digit of $a_{n-1}$ instead of the new digit in $a_n$? For any final digit of $a_{n-1}$, there are at least two possibilities for the new digit. Sometimes, all three are possible.

Comment: One way to do this is to just look at the different cases. So start off and suppose that you are working with a ternary sequence, and that the first two elements are not both zero or 1. Then what are the possibilities for the third element? This approach allows you to extend this type of reasoning out in an inductive manner (since the inductive step is really nothing more than the base case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are assuming that the number of such strings of length $n-1$ starting with $0$, $1$, and $2$ are all equal (and so getting your figures of $\frac{2}{3}a_{n-1}$ by removing the ones which start with a $0$, for instance). This is not in fact the case, as you can see by looking at the strings of length $2$: there are three such strings that start with a $2$, and only two such strings each starting with a $0$ or a $1$.

Instead:  consider any such string of length $n-1$.  We can make a string of length $n$ by appending either of the two digits which are not the same as the one at the end of the string to the end (e.g., if the string ends in $0$, you can append $1$ or $2$).  There are $2a_{n-1}$ ways to do this.  On the other hand, to any such string of length $n-2$ we can append "22".  I'll leave it to you to convince yourself that these are in fact the only possibilities, so that $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

let $a_n^j$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $j \in S=\{0,1,2\}$ denote the number of strings of length $n$ which contain neither of the substrings $00$ and $11$, and with the $n^{th}$ symbol $j$ and define $$a_n = \sum_{k \in S} a_n^k$$

we have $\forall j \in S $ 
$$a_0^j = 0\\
a_1^j = 1$$ 
and $\forall n \gt 1 $ we have
$$ a_n^2 = a_{n-1}\\
a_n^1 = a_{n-1}^0 +a_{n-1}^2\\
a_n^0 = a_{n-1}^1 +a_{n-1}^2\\
$$
adding the three equations together gives
$$
a_n = a_{n-1}+(a_{n-1}^0+a_{n-1}^1 +a_{n-1}^2)+a_{n-1}^2 \\
= 2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}
$$